# Wine install on Jessie: "E: Unable to locate package winehq-devel"

Tags: debian, wine

I am trying to install Wine on Debian 8 using these instructions:

```
 sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

This works.

```
wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
```

This works.

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ JESSIE  main
```

This gives me:

> -su: deb: command not found

Then, if I try to finish install with:

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-devel
```

I get:

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package winehq-devel

Answer (score 6):

The `deb` line isn't a command, it's a configuration line you need to add, either to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or better, to a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (say `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list`. Once you've done that,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winehq-devel
```

should work.

Instead of doing that though, you could install the Debian-maintained package. To get a recent version of Wine, add `deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by either

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install wine
```

for the current stable release, 1.8.4 as of October 2016, or

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install wine-development
```

for the latest development release (after it's migrated to Debian testing), 1.9.19 as of October 2016.

Comment: How do I add the config line (the first thing you said?)

Comment: With an editor, or you can run `echo deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ jessie main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list` from the command line.

Comment: I followed above instructions in this order: your comment, then your answer. With "sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install wine-development" I get "Reading package lists... Error!
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
root@localhost:~# sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install wine-development
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'jessie-backports' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources"

Comment: Had to make separate comment for this due to char limit, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: That error message means your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list` file is incorrect. You need to correct it so that it says `deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ jessie main` (or just use the command I gave, which will overwrite the file with the correct contents).